# Comparing $X^{-1}(E(X| \mathscr{G})(A))$ and $A$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Is it true that $X^{-1}(E(X| \mathscr{G})(A)) = A$ where $A \in \mathscr{F} $  and $A\notin \mathscr{G}$ where $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ is the probability space?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not true.

First of all, in general $E[X \mid \mathscr{G}]$ is only defined up to sets of measure zero, so $E[X \mid \mathscr{G}](A)$ is not a well defined set.

But setting this aside, try a probability space with two points: $\Omega = \{a,b\}$ with $\mathscr{F} = 2^\Omega$ and $P(\{a\}) = P(\{b\}) = 1/2$.  Set $X(a) = 1$ and $X(b) = -1$ so that $X$ is a fair coin flip.  Take $\mathscr{G} = \{\Omega, \emptyset\}$ to be the trivial $\sigma$-field; then $E[X \mid \mathscr{G}]$ is the constant random variable equal to $E[X] = 0$.  Now let $A = \{a\}$.  Since $E[X \mid \mathscr{G}]$ is constant we have $E[X \mid \mathscr{G}](A) = \{0\}$.  But $X^{-1}(\{0\}) = \emptyset \ne A$.

Comment: How about $\subseteq$ instead? OP asks for comparing

Comment: @BCLC: On the same space, let $Y$ be the constant random variable 0 and $A = \{a\}$.

Comment: Nate Eldredge, I don't get it. We still have ∅⊆A right?

Comment: @BCLC: In this example, $E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}] = 0$ so $E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}](A) = \{0\}$ and $Y^{-1}(\{0\}) = \Omega$.  And $\Omega \not\subseteq A$.